# linq group messages show only last ones as whats app do

Tags: linq, chat

I want to do a whats app style chat app.
So, I have a message table as columns like 
senderName, receiverName, message, messageTime
and I have Users table as columns like 
ID, UserName

I want to show whats app style window that shows last messages with names.
So user can click it and see all messages from this user.

For example

---

John

### Hi, Iam here. (date)

Gabriel

### That was true. (date)

```
      db.Messages
     .Where(x => x.senderName == sessionName|| x.receiverName == sessionName).OrderByDescending(x => 
      x.Id).ToList()
     .GroupBy(m => new { V = m.senderName , V1 = m.receiverName })
     .Select(x => x.First());
```

I have tried this. But this has problems.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i write linq query for left whats app panel

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail than what you have here to get an adequate response. Please include the classes for your message objects and Users, so others can see the shape and relationships of the data. That should help the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working example of what you are looking for; showing the latest message (by highest id) for a sender for a particular session

```
void Main()
{
    var messages = GetMessages();

    var latest = messages
        .GroupBy(m => m.SessionName)
        .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Id).First())
        .ToList();

    latest.ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine($"{l.SenderName}\r\n{l.MessageText} ({l.SendDate:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss})"));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SessionName { get; set; }
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    public string ReceiverName { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; } 
    public DateTime SendDate { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages()
{
    return new[] 
    {
        new Message
        {
            Id = 1,
            SessionName = "Savage",
            SenderName = "James T. Kirk",
            ReceiverName = "Kahn",
            MessageText = "Why would a Starfleet admiral ask a three-hundred-year-old frozen man for help?",
            SendDate = new DateTime(2320, 5, 19, 15, 0, 0)
        },
        new Message
        {
            Id = 2,
            SessionName = "Savage",
            SenderName = "Kahn",
            ReceiverName = "James T. Kirk",
            MessageText = "Because I am better.",
            SendDate = new DateTime(2320, 5, 19, 15, 0, 10)
        },
        new Message
        {
            Id = 3,
            SessionName = "Savage",
            SenderName = "James T. Kirk",
            ReceiverName = "Kahn",
            MessageText = "At what?",
            SendDate = new DateTime(2320, 5, 19, 15, 0, 20)
        },
        new Message
        {
            Id = 4,
            SessionName = "Savage",
            SenderName = "Kahn",
            ReceiverName = "James T. Kirk",
            MessageText = "Everything. Alexander Marcus needed to respond to an uncivilized threat in a civilized time, and for that, he needed a warrior's mind - my mind - to design weapons and warships.",
            SendDate = new DateTime(2320, 5, 19, 15, 0, 30)
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks but in your example. James T. Kirk and Kahn are speaking and we see in the shortcut window two messages but we should see only one message, because we have only one conversation. we should see 1 conversation shortcut for 1 conversation. We should see 2 shortcut if there is 2 conversation. And this shortcuts should be with last sender's name on header and his speach under it. This is what whats app do, in left side shortcut panel.

Comment: Okay, that's easy to fix, just group by session name. I've updated my answer

Comment: But in real project the sessionName is equal to Session["username"], there is not a sessionname column in database table, If user logged in as Khan, sessionname = "Khan", and messages has no SessionName header, There is only a SenderName and ReceiverName.

Comment: So what combination of information defines a session as stored in the database? Is it the combination of sender and receiver? If so, then change the group to `GroupBy(grp => new { m.senderName, m.receiverName })`. The rest is the same.

Comment: if sender is Khan and if there is no answer, There will be a shortcut as Khan and no one elses name. This is a problem. In whatsapp you not see your name.
And if you click your name, you can not see details of conversation with your name selected.
As I pointed in my question I have already tried this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatsapp, you need to be more detailed in what you expect to see given a set of data.

Comment: Thanks Carlo for your answers